# Yii2 session is reloaded on every page refresh

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

So the problem is what the title says. The `frontend` session is reset on every page refresh. The `backend` one works fine. My config looks like ( frontend ):

```
'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => '_frontendSessionId',
            'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../runtime/sessions'
        ],
```

No file is created in `__DIR__ . '/../runtime/sessions` folder. Also there is no `_frontendSessionId` in the browsers cookies. What can cause this? Thank you!

Comment: As of right now, the only thing I can think of is to check folder write access. That was the problem for me some time ago.

Comment: Nope. Tried that. Really don't get it. Yesterday it was OK. I literally did nothing since then.

Comment: No suggestions ? What can cause this issue ?

Comment: This could mean that there's a problem reading/settings cookies. Could you check that ? Is your "key" for cookies properly configured ?

Comment: Try also to switch to DbSession just to see if it's a problem with "sessions" or the "file storage mechanism"

Comment: Test once on DbSession.

Answer (score 1):

I have your problem finally I use this code in every page I need session

```
$_SESSION['referrer_page']=Yii::$app->request->referrer;
```

Comment: You are setting the previous page in the session referrer but I got a cart, where my products should be stored in  the session. The previous page is not what I am interested for.

Answer (score 1):

1- Please edit savePath:

```
'savePath' => dirname(__DIR__) .'/frontend/runtime/sessions';  //Or whatever you prefer
```

2- Please make sure the session is active when you open the frontend page. (Login or ....)

```
$session = \Yii::$app->session;
$session->open();
```

Good luck.